# Remove invalid character like '¥' from XML

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have an XML file out of which I read several tags in a WCF service. The XML is of the form as given below:

```
....
<field type="text" name="name">ABCD EFGH</field>
<field type="text" name="address">XYZ</field>
<field type="text" name="details">Random Data --""¥ 5</field>
....
```

As you can see, the third tag gets random data.
Now, I read the data from the XML and execute a procedure to which I pass a custom XML file that I have created in the WCF web service as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ItemList>
    <Item>
        <ColumnName>[name]</ColumnName>
        <ColumnValue>ABCD EFGH</ColumnValue>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ColumnName>[address]</ColumnName>
        <ColumnValue>AJX-AA8-A6J-FQ</ColumnValue>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ColumnName>[details]</ColumnName>
        <ColumnValue>Random Data ¥ 5</ColumnValue>
    </Item>
</ItemList>
</Root>
```

I parse the XML file in the procedure and just insert the data into database.

I have gotten rid of most of the special characters from the XML using the following functions:

```
public static string CleanXMLString(String xmlText)
    {
        string pattern = "[\\~#%&*{}/:<>?|\"'-]";
        string replacement = "";

        Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern);
        string sanitized = regEx.Replace(xmlText, replacement);
        return sanitized;
    }
```

And

```
public static string RemoveInvalidXmlChars(string text)
    {
        if (IsValidXmlString(text))
        {
            var validXmlChars = text.Where(ch => XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(ch)).ToArray();
            return new string(validXmlChars);
        }
        else
            return "";
    }
```

But, I still can't get rid of certain special characters like: ¥

Due to this, the execution of the procedure in SQL Server 2008 causes to return "Invalid XML character"

Could you guys help me out with a generalized solution for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What's your definition of a valid character in your context? Just numbers and letters?

Comment: The [yen/yuan sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A5) ¥ is not an "invalid XML character". It is valid. Maybe you are really seeing [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) problems?

Comment: @frenchie Hey, sorry for the late reply. But I haven't defined anything as a valid/invalid character. So no constraints whatsoever. But the problem seems to be occuring when I pass the XML to the stored procedure.

Comment: I think that the problem seems to be in the stored procedure. My stored procedure takes the XML as a parameter and is defined as:
   `alter procedure [procedure_name]
   @MyXML XML`

Should I have used something else?@JeppeStigNielsen @frenchie

Answer (score 0):

If assume that an `ASCII` character is a valid character then it can be done with this:

```
public string JustAscii(string source)
{
    return new string(source.Where(c => c <= sbyte.MaxValue).ToArray());
}
```

None `ASCII` characters has code bigger than `127`.

Comment: Note, however, that creating a new `string` instance for each iteration of the `foreach` loop is quite inefficient. You could use a `StringBuilder`, or something like `new string(source.Where(c => c <= sbyte.MaxValue).ToArray())`.

Comment: @afsharm Hey, thanks. Your solution seems to work. But I would like to know the reason why '¥' was giving me an invalid xml symbol in SQL stored procedure.

Comment: @HardikTrivedi Maybe `MS SQL` Xml field type does not support Unicode by default. Consider event text fields does not support Unicode by default too. A `varchar` field type is not `Unicode` supported but `nvarchar` is able to support `Unicode`.